# Use a renderer to customize the tabbar icons, but keeping the settings set in AppShell.xaml

Tags: xamarin.forms, styles, tabbar, renderer, app-shell

I created an AppShell app, I customized the Shellcontent with a renderer in order to change the icon when it is clicked, the only problem is that the style of the tabbar that I had set in the resource dictionary is not calculated and therefore the tabbar is returned to default settings.

This is the code of the AppShell.xaml

```
<Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="White" />
            <!--<Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="Black"/>-->
            <Setter Property="Shell.NavBarIsVisible" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="Green"/>-->
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>
```

This is the code of Renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShell), typeof(MyShellRenderer))]
```

namespace AFI.Droid
{
public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
public MyShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
{
}

```
    protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
    {
        return new CustomBottomNavAppearance();
    }
}

public class CustomBottomNavAppearance : IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
    {

    }



    public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
    {
        //SETTARE IN BASE AI GRUPPI
        IMenu myMenu = bottomView.Menu;
        if (App.UTENTE == "Afi")
        {
            IMenuItem myItemOne = myMenu.GetItem(0);
            if (myItemOne.IsChecked)
            {
                myItemOne.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Dashboard_hover);
            }
            else
            {
                myItemOne.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Dashboard);
            }
```

Is there any way to make sure to keep the settings I have given in the style?

Comment: Had you test the ResourceDictionary without the custom renderer? I had create a custom renderer and the UI displayed as withou it.

Comment: Yes, if I remove the renderer the resource dictionary works without problems, the problem arises with the inclusion of the renderer

Comment: You can try to add the `<ResourceDictionary>` into the app.xaml.